# Java - Using Generics for multiple Types

Tags: java, generics

I have the following DataSet class where we hold any kind of object. Mostly to transfer objects from the server to the client. The `contents` variable can hold any serializable object. It could be custom written class Objects or java classes like `Integer`, `String` etc.

I'm trying to convert this into generics. How should we go about converting this into Generics at the same time, I would like to make sure that I don't have to change all the containing object class code, since we are even using `String` and `Integer` classes within the contents.

I have simplified the class to only show some relevant fields and methods.

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Vector;

public class DataSet implements Serializable, PropertyChangeListener{

    Hashtable contents = new Hashtable();

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void addObject(Object obj){
        Vector vector = (Vector)contents.get(obj.getClass());
        if (vector == null){
            vector = new Vector();
            vector.add(obj);
            contents.put(obj.getClass(), vector);
        }
    }

    public Vector getObjects(Class objType){
        if (contents.contains(objType)){
            return (Vector)contents.get(objType);
        }
        else{
            return new Vector();
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate your prompt replies. But, after reviewing the three answers below, I felt like I didn't convey the problem correct.

To make this the way I want, if I invoke dataset.getObjects(of E type), I should be getting a vector of E type. I shouldn't be casting into (Vector). Because I want the contents to be holding `Class<E>`, and `Vector<E>` of key value pairs. If we can do that, then only I could say that this is `safe`.

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
Vector<String> strings = ds.getObjects(String.class);
Vector<Integer> integer = ds.getObjects(Integer.class);
Vector<Employee> employees = ds.getObjects(Employee.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, stay away from class `Vector`, it's obsolete; use `ArrayList` instead.

Here's a simple way to store heterogeneous objects while avoiding explicit casting when retrieving objects. I'm sure you can work this model into your solution.

**UPDATED**, thanks to advice from [Paul Bellora](https://stackoverflow.com/users/697449/paul-bellora).

```
public class DataSet { 

    private Map<Class<?>, List<?>> contents;

    public DataSet(){
       contents = new HashMap<Class<?>, List<?>>();  
    } 

    @SuppressWarnings(value = { "unchecked" })
    public <T> void addObject(Class<T> klass, T object){
        List<T> objectsList = (List<T>)contents.get(klass);
        if (objectsList == null){
            objectsList = new ArrayList<T>();            
            contents.put(klass, objectsList);
        }
        objectsList.add(object);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings(value = { "unchecked" })
    public <T> List<T> getObjects(Class<T> klazz) {
        return contents.containsKey(klazz) ? 
                contents.get(klazz) : Collections.EMPTY_LIST;
    }

    public static <S, T extends Iterable<S>> void print(T list){
        for (Object element : list){
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] o){
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
       ds.addObject(String.class, "save the earth!");
       ds.addObject(String.class, "firing now!");       
       ds.addObject(Integer.class, new Integer(100));
       ds.addObject(Boolean.class, new Boolean(true));

       print(ds.getObjects(String.class));
       print(ds.getObjects(Boolean.class));
       print(ds.getObjects(Integer.class));      
    }
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I Like this better. I wasn't aware of the syntax "public <T> T getObject(Class<T> klass)" that you have used. Only thing is, I would like to hold a Class<T> as the key and Vector<T> of that type of the value. Not an Object. Object is too generic for me and considered not safe. If we can get that done, I'm good. This is part of a huge framework that we have in our local environment and it is not easy to change all the other referring classes. I agree that we can have ArrayList. It wouldn't make a difference for me in converting into Generics.

Comment: What do you mean "hold a Class<T> as the key"? The class name, hash code of the object, what?

Comment: Hashtable will hold key value pairs, in such away that key will be of certain type and the value will be a Vector of that type. For example, Hashtable will have 1. java.lang.String as the key and Vector<String> as the value. 2. custom.pkg.Employee as the key and the Vector<custom.pkg.Employee> as the value. I hope you understand. As you clearly identified, this Hashtable will have more than a single type of key value pairs.

Comment: I would just use `Class<?>` as the key - that's what the type-safe heterogenous container pattern usually looks like. Allowing other strings besides the class names seems problematic anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this would be sufficient:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.List;

public class DataSet implements Serializable, PropertyChangeListener{

    Map<Class<?>, Vector<Serializable>> contents = new HashMap<Class<?>, Vector<Serializable>>();

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void <T extends Serializable> addObject(T obj){
        Vector<T> vector = (Vector<T>)contents.get(obj.getClass());
        if (vector == null){
            vector = new Vector<T>();
            contents.put(obj.getClass(), vector);
        }
        vector.add(obj);
    }

    public <T extends Serializable> Vector<T> getObjects(Class<T> objType){
        if (contents.contains(objType)){
            return (Vector<T>)contents.get(objType);
        }
        else{
            return new Vector<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

I've edited my original post. Indeed, as pointed by [Duncan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/474189/duncan) in his comments, a DataSet structure has no point of being generic itself. Still, some generics could still add some syntax sugar in attempt to avoid casting

Comment: I don't think `DataSet` should be generic, since the intention is to store objects of all types. FWIW, I'm not your down-voter.

Comment: contents should hold Vector list if Serializable objects,wildcard does not solve it.See OP

Comment: @KumarAbhinav, you have a point, wildcard is not helpful there.

Comment: Duncan is right. I cannot make the dataset generic. Because it can hold any kind of object. Again, I have modified the question. To make this the way I want, if I invoke dataset.getObjects(of E type), I should be getting a vector of E type. I shouldn't be casting into (Vector). Because I want the contents to be holding Class<E>, and Vector<E> of key value pairs. If we can do that, then only I could say that this is safe. Am I expecting too much or trying to do impossible ??

Comment: @Duncan, Indeed you are correct. I've taken your point and removed the generic on the class-level. It seems it fits better on a method level, where the consumer would benefit from an avoided type-casts

Comment: @user3656845, see the latest changes I've made. Your dataset indeed should not be generic, but you can still benefit from generics. In this case, you will have type-casts avoided.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken ,your `Hashtable` **contents** variable hold the class of a `Serializable` Object as key and the  Serializable `Vector` List as value

```
   import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
    import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
    import java.io.Serializable;
    import java.util.Hashtable;
    import java.util.Vector;

    public class DataSet implements Serializable, PropertyChangeListener{

        Hashtable<Class,Vector<Serializable> contents = new Hashtable<Class,Vector<Serializable>();

        @Override
        public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void addObject(Serializable obj){

            Vector<Serializable> vector = contents.get(obj.getClass());
            if (vector == null){
                vector = new Vector<Serializable>();
                vector.add(obj);
                contents.put(obj.getClass(), vector);
              }
            else{
              vector.add(obj);
               }
        }

        public Vector<Serializable> getObjects(Class objType){
            if (contents.contains(objType)){
                return (Vector<Serializable>)contents.get(objType);
            }
            else{
                return new Vector<Serializable>();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your "Hashtable<Class,Vector<Serializable> contents = new Hashtable<>();" @"Kumar Abhinav" is giving me a compilation issue.

Comment: @user3656845 Its a diamind operator,newly introduced in Java 7 only..Read Diamond operator

Comment: @user3656845 You can use the normal inference type on both sides.

Comment: I modified the question a little bit. When I invoke getObjects(Class<E>), I should be getting Vector<E>.

Comment: @user3656845 I think my program works perfectly fine for the above case